# How do I solve this PDE with three variables using the Method of Characteristics?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Would you please help me to solve this PDE?

$u_x-u_y+u=z$, with $u=u(x, y, z)$

Where: $u(0,y, z)=y^2e^z$

When I try to use The method of characteristics in higher dimension,I get the wrong answer.

it's an exercise on Basic Partial Differential Equations by David Bleecker and George Csordas, Page 107 ,second Q.

Comment: $$u=z+e^{z-x}(x+y)^2$$

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? See [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)